# VBA 1000 Email Addresses - Send Groups Of 20

Tags: vba, list, email, outlook

From a Column A list of 1,000 email addresses, how would you send same email in groups of 20 addresses from the list at a time ?

```
Sub SendEmail()
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim MItem As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim email_ As String
Dim cc_ As String
Dim subject_ As String
Dim body_ As String

 'Create Outlook object
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 'Loop through the rows
For Each cell In Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    email_ = cell.Value
    subject_ = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    body_ = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    cc_ = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value

    'Create Mail Item and send it
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    With MItem
        .To = email_
        .CC = cc_
        .Subject = subject_
        .Body = body_
        
            
        .Display
    End With
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: What about subject, body and cc?  They're all the same value?

Comment: How would it be coded to either have the same subject, body and cc for all ... or have different for each group of twenty ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```vb
Sub SendEmail()
    Const SEND_EVERY As Long = 20
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim email_ As String
    Dim cc_ As String, subject_ As String, body_ As String, i As Long, first As Boolean
    
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    i = 0
    first = True
    'Loop through the rows
    For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    
        i = i + 1      '<< fixed here
        If first Then
            'the first cell in a batch: collect common info and first address
            email_ = cell.Value
            subject_ = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            body_ = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            cc_ = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            first = False
        Else
            email_ = email_ & ";" & cell.Value 'just add the email
        End If
        
        If i Mod SEND_EVERY = 0 Then 'on the 20th cell or a multiple of that?
            CreateMail OutlookApp, email_, cc_, subject_, body_ 'send accumulated
            first = True                                    'reset flag
        End If
    
    Next cell
    
    'send any remaining items
    If i Mod SEND_EVERY > 0 Then
        CreateMail OutlookApp, email_, cc_, subject_, body_
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub CreateMail(oApp As Object, sTo, sCC, sSubject, sBody)
    With oApp.CreateItem(0)
        .To = sTo
        .CC = sCC
        .Subject = sSubject
        .Body = sBody
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am using Excel 2007 on Win 10 64 bit. Would that combination cause the macro to not function as desired ? It is pasting all 100 emails (I am currently using a sample of 100 rows in Col A) in the TO field ... rather than pasting 20 emails (Rows 1 - 20) send email ... then pasting next 20 rows/email addresses and send that email .. etc.   ???  Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: My bad - I had `i = 1 + 1` instead of `i = i + 1`  Fixed above

Comment: Great ! That works.  I've tried manipulating the code so the 20 email addresses are displayed in the CC field or in the BCC field. No luck.Would you be so kind to help me with that as well ?

Comment: Pretty sure you need at least one "To" address: you could put the rest in CC or BCC  - just concatenate as shown for the "To" field.

Comment: Thank you ! It works with the CC and the BCC now. Kudos to you and CHEERS !